# Error: The expanduser('~') cannot be added to dirs. 'xxx':'xxx"

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, operating-system

I am trying to read a dirs from a file and add the expanduser('~')
But there is an error. It doesn't add 'C:\Users\kanna'
dir_reader.py:

```
def dir_reader(x):
    import os
    f1 = open(x, 'r')
    var0 = []
    var2 = []
    for data in f1:
        var0.append(data)
    home = os.path.expanduser('~')
    for i in range(len(var0)):
        var1 = var0[i]
        var3 = var1.lstrip("'/''~").rstrip("\'\n'")
        vs = os.path.join(home, var3)
        var2.append(vs)
    return var2
```

output:

```
['C:\\OpenCity\\Premium\\premium_users.txt', 'C:\\OpenCity\\Premium\\premium_users.usra', 'C:\\OpenCity\\Plugins\\', 'C:\\OpenCity\\Hacked_Version_Official\\hacked_files_official_users.txt', 'C:\\OpenCity\\Hacked_Version_Official\\hacked_files_official_users.usra']
```

files.txt:

```
'~\OpenCity\Premium\premium_users.txt'
'~\OpenCity\Premium\premium_users.usra'
'~\OpenCity\Plugins\'
'~\OpenCity\Hacked_Version_Official\hacked_files_official_users.txt'
'~\OpenCity\Hacked_Version_Official\hacked_files_official_users.usra'
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but you can simply use `for var1 in var0:`.

Comment: Did you try `print(home)` to see if it's being set as you expect?

Comment: @Barmar I tried and posted here. See output.

Comment: @ekhumoro I will try it and say to you.

Comment: The output you showed is `var2`, not `home`.

Comment: No @Barmar var2 is the output.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you very much. It is working properly.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: the home is the expanduser('~') but the var2 is the only output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stripping the wrong separator, which means `var3` will remain an absolute path, and `join` will throw away everything from `home` other than the drive.

Use `var3 = var1.strip("~\\/' \n")` instead.